# Pandas - How can I group by one numeric column and filter rows from each group by the median of each group?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-science

I have a dataset consisting of one ID, one categorical variable "A" and one numerical variable "B".
I want to group by "A" and filter the rows **from each group** to get only the rows that are avobe or equal to the median of "B" (the median should be calculated for each group).
Example:

| ID | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Category 1 | 0.5 |
| 2 | Category 2 | 0.2 |
| 3 | Category 1 | 0.2 |
| 4 | Category 1 | 0.6 |
| 5 | Category 2 | 0.4 |

My expected result would be:

| ID | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Category 1 | 0.5 |
| 4 | Category 1 | 0.6 |
| 5 | Category 2 | 0.4 |

Being the median of category 1 = 0.5 and 0.3 for category 2.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

```
out = df[df.groupby("A")["B"].transform(lambda x: x >= x.median())]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
   ID           A    B
0   1  Category 1  0.5
3   4  Category 1  0.6
4   5  Category 2  0.4
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you! What if the filter were to be higher than 125% of the median (the value of the median plus 25%). I tried `out = df[df.groupby("A")["B"].transform(lambda x: x >= x.median()*1.25)]`  and it didnt work

Comment: @TomasRodriguezPons `out = df[df.groupby("A")["B"].transform(lambda x: x >= x.median() * 1.25)]` prints only `5  Category 2  0.4`. Is this incorrect?